# SSRS how to render multiple "Body" for different dataset?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have `2 datasets D1 and D2`

My report design is a fixed layout as follow, My `D1` and `D2` table will group at `6` rows and extra rows shall continue the next page. The problem is if I group the `D1` at `6` and break, `D2` will not show in the first page.

I understand `D1` and `D2` will render continuously in the body even if you have a page break.

What I want is like having 2 Body section and each one have a prefix size. Is there any solution for this ?

```
__________________
Header            

__________________

D1                
Row 1  
Row 2

Row 6     

D2                
Row 1  
Row 2

Row 6     
__________________

Footer            
__________________
```

Comment: You can achieve it with sub-reports

Comment: These are separate tables with different datasets

Comment: You can create one report for each table, and then use these as sub-reports on the main one.

Comment: Can you explain more on how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

1- Create a report for D1, showing 6 lines, with no headers or footers

2- Create a report for D2, showing 6 lines, with no headers or footers

3- Create empty parent report

4- Insert headers on the parent report

5- Right click on the body of the parent report and select insert->subreport

6- Right click on the newly created subreport, then subreport properties and select the subreport 1

7- Repeat 5 and 6 for subreport 2

8- Resize the layout as you please

9- Insert footers